# PHPのヘッダでダウンロードファイル名を指定した時のIEの挙動について

Tags: php

こんにちは、お世話になります。

PHPのヘッダで、下記のような感じでファイル名を指定しています。

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test#1.txt"');
```

この記述で、FirefoxやMicrosoftEdgeなどのブラウザではうまくいくんですが、IE11だとシャープがアンダーラインに置き換わってしまい、ダウンロードしたファイル名が「test_1.txt」となってしまいます。  
　これを解決する方法はありますでしょうか。  
　もし方法があるようでしたら、教えていただけると幸いです。  
　以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ファイル名をURLエンコードして実行すれば可能です。
文字コードがわかんないですが、とりあえず以下のように実施してみてください。

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=UTF-8\'\''.rawurlencode("test#1.txt"));
```

レガシーなブラウザによっては効かない可能性がありますので、必要なブラウザでチェックをしてください。

参考URL
https://qiita.com/takehironet/items/79c025e4140e29c57abe
https://qiita.com/khsk/items/d541b8dc40bd2c6128d2
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266

Comment: ありがとうございます。うまくいきました。